# Laravel url in ajax not pass to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

I am using ajax and laravel 5.4 in my ajax function  it return email correctly and it goes to url and return success message my console window but didnot show the url page

Ajax funtion

```
 $("body").on('click','.btn-info', function(e){
        var email = [];
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
           email.push($(this).parent().siblings().eq(2).text());

        });
         //alert(email);

         getDetails(email);
    });

     function getDetails(data) {
           $.ajax({ 
            type: "GET",
            url:"http://birdys.app/admin/sendpromocode",
            data: {email: data},
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //dataType: "json",
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });

        function successFunc(data, status) {
            //data =JSON.parse(data);
            alert(data);
            console.log(data);

        }   

        function errorFunc(xhr, error) {
             console.log(error);
             console.log(xhr);
        }
     }
```

route:

My route inside group function

```
 Route::get('/sendpromocode', 'Admin\UserController@sendpromocode')->name('admin.sendpromocode');
```

controller:

```
public function sendpromocode(Request $request)
    {

         return $request->email;
    }
```

Why it doesnot go that url page

Comment: not sure what you mean by "did not show the URL page". You say the ajax call reaches the controller, yes? And it sends the email, yes? And it returns a result inside the "success" function? If it does all of those things, then the ajax call has finished correctly. What else were you expecting to happen? Ajax does not cause a postback or page refresh.

Comment: my function is get the email for selected checkbox and pass to controller and request that email 
in my page...But while execute the code it show email in my alert and console but  i want to return email
in mycontroller page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code I see route should be without admin(if you have not any route groups with prefix). Change Route add /admin before sendpromocode and try again.

```
Route::get('/admin/sendpromocode', 'Admin\UserController@sendpromocode')->name('admin.sendpromocode');
```

Comment: No problem its inside that group function admin

Comment: And please explain what you mean  'but didnot show the url page' ?

Comment: my function is get the email for selected checkbox and pass to controller and request that email 
in my page...But while execute the code it show email in my alert and console but  i want to return email
in mycontroller page.

Comment: maybe yous should reload page with your url and params ?
use window.location.href ='Your url with get params';

Comment: how to pass url with params

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142814/discussion-between-vahe-galstyan-and-karthiga).

Comment: @VaheGalstyan "maybe yous should reload page with your url and params". Personally I'd say that returning from an ajax call and then immediately doing a full page refresh is an anti-pattern. That way you make two requests to the server, when all the work could easily be done in one request (either ajax or full postback). Either the full details required should be returned as the response to the ajax call, and then JS used to manipulate the page as required, or remove the ajax and do a full postback with the required params, and update the whole page as per the result.